# Xojo Word Automation on Mac

Tags: ms-word, applescript, xojo

So, I'm trying to access Xojo's office automation plugins but they're only accessible on windows. Is there anyway I could still use Xojo's office automation plugins via Applescript?

Comment: You should check with Xojo's developer. it seems like Xojo is written in VBA according to standard Microsoft protocols, so there's no reason I know of why it shouldn't work on Mac Office. At any rate, AppleScript won't help implementing plugins. You'd have to rewrite the functions you need entirely in AppleScript (which is doable, but a serious PITA).